# JMeter While Controller

Tags: controller, while-loop, jmeter

I have searched as crazy for the solution to my problem throughout the web, but none exist yet. My problem is that I have to check if I get specific text in HTTP request, which is in a while loop and if I do, then I should leave the loop and continue with the thread or stop the thread completely if text doesn't exist. I have set it up as follows:

```
Thread Group
.. While controller
   .. HTTP request
      .. Response Assertion
Listener
```

I used LAST in the while controller and set HTTP response to false text and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Hope the following one will work for you:

```
Thread Group
    HTTP Request
    //set-found-condition
    ${__setProperty(txtFound,FALSE,)}
    While Controller
    // invert value in condition - will be executed while txtFound == FALSE
    Condition = ${__BeanShell(!props.get("txtFound")}
    . . .
    [execute your test logic here]
    . . .
    YOUR HTTP Request
        Response Assertion
        // set your text assertion here
        // this will results in ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} = TRUE if text found
    IF Controller    --FOUND
    // if text found set separate variable or property - e.g. ${txtFound} - into TRUE
    Condition = ${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}
        HTTP Request 
        //set-found-condition
        ${__setProperty(txtFound,TRUE,)}  // this will be inverted to FALSE in the next WHILE cycle's condition, WHILE cycle will be exited
    . . .
```

I think you may also easily use [JSR / BSF / BeanShell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) attached to **YOUR HTTP Request** to set `txtFound` property into TRUE instead of cumbersome construction with IF.

Comment: Thanks for the idea ... using a BSF PreProcessor as a child of the While Controller allowed me to have the condition evaluated by the While Controller properly.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Thread Group
xpath_Extractor or regex_extractor( variable = VAR_1 )
.. While controller( ${__javaScript("${VAR_1}" != "REQUIRED")} )
   .. HTTP request
Listener
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller

The WHILE controller will execute until something is set to `FALSE`.  By setting the condition as `LAST`, you won't exit the controller until the last sample **FAILS**.   Are you using an assertion to FAIL the sample if it contains the text you want?

A cleaner way might be to a use a beanshell assertion to set a value to false.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Response assertion to fail the sample if text is not present.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to get around this issue was create a Regular Expression Extractor and set it up so that it would inevitably fail and set my variable to FAIL.  Then I set my while loop to **${__javaScript("${projLoad}" != "SUCCESS")}**

Under my conditions I created that same RegEx Extractor to fail again but changed the default value to **SUCCESS**

It's probably not the cleanest, but works like a charm