# JMeter: Practical example of "IF Controller" and "While Controller"

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, controller, jmeter

Can anyone please give me a practical example of the use of "IF Controller"and "While Controller" for www.google.com

I went through the descriptions of "IF Controller" and "While Controller"but that seems unclear or confusing for starters, however, rest all controllers are understood to me.

I would like to have simple example of use of If and While Controller for www.google.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Example algorithm:

- While ("Next" link is present)

  - If (Response contains expected page link)

    - HTTP Request to the expected page link
  - (Else) HTTP Request to "Next" SERP

References:

- [jMeter - Regular Expressions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_regular_expressions.htm) - to determine whether "Next" link is present or SERP contains expected URL
- [How to use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and get Pie.](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie)
- [JMeter While Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886132/jmeter-while-controller)